# Shift MapBox 500px

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I am currently working on a project which requires MapBox to be used. We have a persistent sidebar which is laid over the top of the map in HTML. The sidebar is 500px wide.

Everything works fine, except that when we center the map at a given co-ordinate pair, there is 500 pixels' worth of the map hidden. Essentially, I am looking for a function / formula that can be used to convert the latitude position used for centering to accommodate an extra 500 pixels, at a given zoom level.

Could anyone tell me of such an algorithm (ideally in JavaScript, but could easily be converted)? We have looked into the use [node-sphericalmercator](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sphericalmercator), but this doesn't quite achieve what we need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `L.fitBounds()` and [the padding options](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-paddingtopleft) to do this with Leaflet, or if you can't use bounds, convert with [latLngToPoint](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icrs-latlngtopoint), move the point, and convert back.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware that Leaflet provided this functionality, but someone over on their Forum also pointed this out. Thanks for your help!